# Pass a value to another screen

Tags: powerapps

I have a screen where the user can select an option (not a browse gallery as it does not do what is required).

I want to pass the item the user has selected to the pre-made "DetailScreen1" which is used by the browse gallery.

I looked at the browse screen but did not see how it does it as the navigate onselect event is just normal navigation.

Code:

```
Navigate(DetailScreen1, ScreenTransition.Fade)
```

I want to do something like

```
Navigate(DetailScreen1, ScreenTransition.None {Last(listOfStuff)})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of the [Navigate function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-navigate/) to pass extra parameters to the context of the screen being navigated to. For example, if your first screen has a dropdown and a text input control that you want to pass the values to the next screen, you can use the following expression:

```
Navigate(DetailScreen1, ScreenTransition.Fade, { text: TextInput1.Value, dropdownChoice: Dropdown1.Selected.Value })
```

In the DetailScreen1, you can use those context variables as they'll be available.

Here's an example: the dropdown in the first screen contains a list of sections, and after selecting one you would navigate to another page:

[image: Sample result]

In the "right arrow", we can set the following OnSelect property:

```
Navigate(ProductsScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade, { selectedSection: Dropdown1.Selected.Value })
```

In the ProductsScreen, you can then have a gallery whose items are filtered based on that value that was passed:

```
Items: Filter(AllProducts, Section = selectedSection)
```

Comment: How persistent is this variable?  Does it stay in memory or do you have to re-instantiate it if you move to another screen?  Like current_user for example...?

Comment: The third parameter to `Navigate` will set the value of the [context variable](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/working-with-variables/) in the target screen. Context variables will stay in the memory for that screen, until another value is set to the same variable. For example, if you navigate to screen B passing a value {a:1}, the value of `a` in that screen will continue being 1 until another call (to either Navigate to screen B passing `a` as a parameter or to UpdateContext) changes its value.