# Power Apps Question: Transfer TimerControl Information into an E-mail

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm relatively new to power apps but I've reviewed the TimerControl tool, understand the basics of navigation and can even get it to print the data but I can't seem to get it to do the following

1) Start Timer 
2) Stop Timer 
3) On Timer stop, navigate to e-mail screen, AND put timer information into the body of the e-mail.

Can this be done? If so I'd love to know how.

Here is the main simple screen

[image: Screen one with timer]

I would like on Stop it to navigate to the 2nd screen which is here and paste the timer information int othe message of the e-mail

[image: Screen Two - E-mail form]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify what you mean by "put timer information into the body of the e-mail"? What kind of information do you want from the timer?

Comment: Carlos, certainly. I updated the original question with screenshots, I hope that brings some clarity. I essentially want the total time of the timer added to the message field of the e-mail screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to another screen, you can pass some additional information to that screen (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262911/751090) for more details). You can use that in your case: if you set the OnTimerEnd property of the timer to the following (assuming that your timer control is called `Timer1`):

```
Navigate(Screen2, ScreenTransition.Cover, { timerDuration: Timer1.Duration })
```

Then you can use that value (`timerDuration`) in the second screen. So if you set the Default property of the text input control that has the e-mail message to:

```
"Timer duration: " & timerDuration
```

Then that value will be the default in the e-mail message on that screen.

Comment: Hi Carlos, for some reason when I do the "Timer duration: " & timerDuration, or "Timer duration: " & timer1.Duration it is only spitting out the full duration amount and not the actual time (i.e. 1 minute, 2 minutes, etc.) I copied what you showed so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. @carlosfigueira

Comment: I believe I got it sorted, I need to use & Timer1.Text to get the value I was looking for but you were immensely helpful thank you