# PowerApps Portal--> After Record is created (Insert Form) show that record as Edit Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, powerapps, dynamics-crm-portals, powerapps-portal

I have a Insert form for Account Entity.
Once user create Record, I want to move to another page and show same record as Edit Form.

Does anyone have idea way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of Box configuration helps!!!

There is a field on "Entity Form" records named "Append Record ID to Query String". This is to configure passing the id of the record to the page after form submission. This screenshot shows it in the Redirect Section in the classic interface

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to redirect the user to desired page using `OnSuccess` of form submission.

> **On success**: Select one of the following options:
>
> **Show success message**: Requires a message to be displayed to the
>   user on successful submission of the form. You can also select Hide
>   form on success to hide the form upon successful submission.
>
> **Redirect to webpage**: Redirects the user to the selected webpage
>   in the portal. You must select a webpage from the Redirect to webpage
>   list.
>
> **Redirect to URL**: Redirects the user to the specified URL. You
>   must enter a URL in the Redirect to URL field.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/compose-page#add-form)

Comment: I probably overs implied my question.

Yes on success I have an option to redirect to another web page, which I already have in place. I have also Edit form added to this page.
To show a record on Edit form  I need  to **append the new id to the querystring**
 
How exactly can I inject id to querystring. I mean where can I configure? If I need to do this using Jquery or Javascript then do you have any sample code for this.

Comment: Update: Answer to my last question
_How exactly can I inject id to querystring. I mean where can I configure?_ 
 is in Out of Box configuration in Dynamics Portal Record. i will add an answer so that it will help others as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this several ways.  What I do, is use Navigate() to go to the new screen, and I pass in a context variable to the new edit screen.

Assuming you're using `OnSelect()` on a button to call [SubmitForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-form), you can do the `Navigate()` call via the `OnSuccess()` property of the form.

And within [Navigate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-navigate), you just pass whatever data you need to in order for the next screen to properly bind it to the Edit Form.  This is the UpdateContextRecord optional param.  You'd have the Edit form take its values from a Context Variable.

Passing variables between screens [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232599/pass-a-value-to-another-screen) here, as well.

Comment: Hi Paul,
I think you misunderstood the question with PowerApps, This is rather related to PowerApps- Portals previously called as (Dynamics Portals)

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I'm new to this too.