# How to pass value from one form to another in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a created list with values in it

When I create an item and click on "Next" then it should save and redirect to "Edit form". But instead of showing the values I have entered, it shows the previously edited item.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Edit form]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a value to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232599/pass-a-value-to-another-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the default value of the form.And also one thing you can do is ,you can always filter the First row from the list,so it always shows the latest saved data.

Comment: Please explain how this answers OP's question. What default value and what should it be?

Comment: There is a Default property for each of the fields in form.And since each time 'Next' is clicked values is getting saved and will be on the top row.So always when coming to Edit form,the 'Item' property of Form can be set to First of the list.